# How can I become a pilot in Tanzania?

Tags: flight-training, career

I am a student in Tanzania and it's required to take PGM (physics, geography and math) to qualify for studying as a pilot. After qualifying, what am I supposed to do to study for a CPL, and what help can I get if my financial status is limited? Are there any scholarships for people in this situation?

Comment: people, don't downvote just because the question is not a good fit for the site. have a bit of understanding for a new user who has to learn how the site works in addition to probably having to learn english as a second language.

Comment: @Federico In Tanzania, English is often a _third_ language. But I know many Americans with worse English than this person...

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know how civilian or military pilot training takes place in Tanzania, but I might recommend that you make a visit to a fixed base operator at a local airport there in Tanzania and talk with the staff about flight training.  They may be able to assist your further on that path.

A basic [Google Search for Flight Training in Tanzania](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=flight%20training%20Tanzania) turned up [this place](http://www.flymwaa.com/home).  I don't know how close you are to Dar es Salaam, but they do have a private flight school out there and could better assist you.

As for scholarships for flight training, [check these guys out](https://www.aopa.org/training-and-safety/learn-to-fly/aviation-scholarships).

Oh, and [these guys as well](http://flyaccelerated.com/pilot-loans-pilot-financing-grants/aviation-grants.html).

Good Luck with your training.

Comment: I don't believe the AOPA or the "Fly Accelerated" site has any scholarships outside of the United States. Doing flight training in the United States is not outside the realm of possibility, but it isn't "in Tanzania".